# How to use notifyDataSetChanged() with a viewpager which contains a fragment with a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Each page loads a fragment which contains a ListView. This ListView loads many TextViews which gets text from a static ArrayList. This static ArrayList is updated in a AsyncTask with data from a server. Well, i want to update the ListView, each time the ArrayList is updated. If i use notifyDataSetChanged() on the ViewPager adaptar it does not work, I have to get access to each ListViewadapter. Any suggestions?

This is my AsyncTask doinBackground method:

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        if(socket!=null){
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while(true){
                try {
                    s = in.readLine();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<VirtualSensor>>(){}.getType();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                _sensorComponents =(ArrayList<VirtualSensor>) gson.fromJson(s, type);
                Log.d("Mesage", _sensorComponents.get(1).get_value()+"");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });


            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Update: After some testing i found out that the problem occurs when i have more than 1 page in viewpager. I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: If you dont mind can you post some of your code. So that we can find what the issue is ??..

Comment: Why are you using a **while(true)** in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `EventBus` is a better solution.

Also try this.

Instead of assigning data to your `ArrayList` try adding contents to it.

change this line

```
 _sensorComponents =(ArrayList<VirtualSensor>) gson.fromJson(s, type);
```

to

```
 _sensorComponents.clear();
 _sensorComponents.add((ArrayList<VirtualSensor>) gson.fromJson(s, type));
```

then notify your data set by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

> Well, i want to update the listview, each time the arraylist is updated.

I would consider using Observer Pattern, which would make your code cleaner. Each of fragments then would register its listener and once your dataset is updated (by async taks or by any other means) you broadcast event about it and then fragments can do with it what they want. You may use event buses likes GreenRobot's EventBus or OTTO to save you some time.

Comment: Ok, I've never heard of this but i will read about it. Thanks.

Comment: It's this a good example to make an idea how it works? https://gist.github.com/alexfu/5797429

Comment: Yep, this is fine. You can also check https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/ docs to have most of the job already implemented in that lib so all you can do is create even class, register listeners and broadcast your event when needed

Answer (score 0):

After some testing i found out that the problem occurs when i have more than 1 page in viewpager. I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.